# How to get content from website

Tags: php

I want to use rest api from bit.ly, and the result like this

`http://bit*ly/xxxxxx`

How go get the result use PHP Code?
Thanks

Comment: google Curl php

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents("http://bit*ly/xxxxxx");
?>
```

Or try this code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://bit*ly/xxxxxx";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```